# How to combine two columns to make a third column taking property from group by method?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, max

I don't know if I can ask this question clearly, but here I try!

I have a classification problem in which I have to predict a person's credit score based on his income group. I have used this code:

```
dta.groupby(['income_bracket'])['credit_score'].get_values()
```

Now I have a data table as usual, which looks like this:

```
income_bracket  credit_scores    
    'very low'            0.0             2340
                          1.0              456
    'moderate'            0.0             1234 
                          1.0              657
        'high'            0.0               54
                          1.0              657
   'very high'            0.0                9
                          1.0             1234
```

Explanation:  The data above is saying that, for example, a person with 'very low' income bracket having 0.0 credit score is 2340 and with credit score 1.0 is 456.

Now, is there any way that I can do something like: if a person is in income_bracket, then predict that his credit_score will be MAX(of the credit score in that income bracket)? For example, if someone has an income bracket of 'high', then I can predict his credit_score will be MAX(54,657) = 657 = 1.0

the desired output that i want : newdata --> income_group = 'high' ---> credit_score = 1 ( because i know that in high income group the MAX value is 657 which belong to the credit score of 1.0

Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for get `index` values per group which max value in `val` and then select these rows by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
#dta.reset_index(inplace=True)
#dta = dta.reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'val'}) 
print (dta)
  income_bracket  credit_score   val
0       very low           0.0  2340
1       very low           1.0   456
2       moderate           0.0  1234
3       moderate           1.0   657
4           high           0.0    54
5           high           1.0   657
6      very high           0.0     9
7      very high           1.0  1234
```

```
print (dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax())
income_bracket
very low     0
moderate     2
high         5
very high    7
Name: val, dtype: int64

#select all columns
print (dta.ix[dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax()])
  income_bracket  credit_score   val
0       very low           0.0  2340
2       moderate           0.0  1234
5           high           1.0   657
7      very high           1.0  1234

#select columns income_bracket and credit_score
print (dta.ix[dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax(), 
             ['income_bracket','credit_score']])
  income_bracket  credit_score
0       very low           0.0
2       moderate           0.0
5           high           1.0
7      very high           1.0

#select column credit_score    
print (dta.ix[dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax(), 'credit_score'])
0    0.0
2    0.0
5    1.0
7    1.0
Name: credit_score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: i simplified this question the actual question has about 20 different income bracket , now i got the code upto now but i am not able to get to the final point , i did find the **val** as you defined but how to get a new data point and match with its income group and get the final credit score ?

Comment: Can you add desired output from your input to question? I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: also i think the use of **val** is getting me some problem , the name val is not there with groupby function it is just number , the column is not named when you use groupby , but i am very thankful to you :)

Comment: So do you need ad new column with values `0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1` (plus .0)?

Comment: yaa exactly but not with '0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1' but with '0,0,1,1' you see for each income group there are two credit score but i want just one credit score with the highest count .

Comment: So do you need `print (dta.ix[dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax(), ['income_bracket','credit_score']])` or `print (dta.ix[dta.groupby(['income_bracket'], sort=False)['val'].idxmax(), 'credit_score'])` ?

Comment: Maybe only parameter `sort` and then select columns is necessary.

Comment: I add it to answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121131/discussion-between-anurag-pandey-and-jezrael).